# Couldn't resolve host 'metadata.google.internal'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

My VM was running for 2 years uptime or even more with no problems.
Several days ago I couldn't reach the website it hosts.

I tried ssh but it failed to connect, so I restarted the VM and it fails to boot.

Attaching the log from the serial console.
I see problems resolving metadata server.

What can be wrong?

Thanks!

```
Nov 27 13:21:54 (none) /etc/mysql/debian-start[2326]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
[[36minfo[39;49m] Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were 
not closed cleanly..
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'metadata.google.internal'
Nov 27 13:21:54 (none) google: 
Nov 27 13:21:54 (none) google: No startup script found in metadata.
Nov 27 13:21:54 (none) /etc/mysql/debian-start[2330]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Nov 27 13:21:54 (none) /etc/mysql/debian-start[2330]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Nov 27 13:21:54 (none) /etc/mysql/debian-start[2330]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Nov 27 13:21:54 (none) /etc/mysql/debian-start[2330]: This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.5.52, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
Nov 27 13:21:54 (none) /etc/mysql/debian-start[2377]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
Nov 27 13:21:54 (none) /etc/mysql/debian-start[2382]: Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables
Nov 27 13:21:56 (none) accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
Nov 27 13:22:01 (none) accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
Nov 27 13:22:06 (none) accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
Nov 27 13:22:11 (none) accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
Nov 27 13:22:16 (none) accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
Nov 27 13:22:21 (none) accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
Nov 27 13:22:26 (none) accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
Nov 27 13:22:31 (none) accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
Nov 27 13:22:37 (none) accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
Nov 27 13:22:42 (none) accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
Nov 27 13:22:47 (none) accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

Comment: This question has also been asked in Serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/885401/couldnt-resolve-host-metadata-google-internal

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a networking issue to me. 
Did anything change on that front? Does it live in the default network? I have sometimes seen unexplained behavior caused by some of the presets of auto-routes and FW rules.

Have you tried stopping the machine, snapshotting the disk and starting a new machine with it in a new, clean and separate independent VPC net?

If that works, try it again on another machine placed within the previous network.

- If both new machines work. The networking state of your initial machine is to be investigated.
- If the the machine in the new net works, but not when you place it in the original net, there is some configuration to look at within the net.
- If none work, I'd explore the state of the disk. Are you taking frequent snapshots of it. Have you tried going back in time to a operational state? (and therefore looking at what made it get into trouble)

Let me know how it went.

Comment: Thanks, yes, for me it also looks like a network problem. I don't have much snapshots, tried to make a new instance from one of the snapshots and it could not even start, getting nothing on serial console.. but the new from scratch instance worked fine with network and etc..